# Best way to build a rest middleware in php

Tags: php, api, rest, erp

I have a project to implement and I'm still not quite sure which is the best way to go.

I have to create a middleware for a webshop that addresses the rest API of the connector of the shop system, but also the rest of the connector of the ERP.

I already built this connector with xml files so i'm familiar in using PHP for this.

Now I am wondering how I can map a PHP call as modularly as possible in a PHP pattern, so that I can simply add new calls as files.
The interface of the ERP allowes me to get 10 articles and at the same time gives me a URL with which I can get the next articles, and with a select filter I can choose which fields I want to get back.

Should I now make a standardized call as a function or should I make a separate function for each individual call and how do I map a potential modularity with curl?

I'm just don't think there is a good way to build a curl construct like this

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://restapiurl.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, POST DATA);
$result = curl_exec($ch);


print_r($result);
curl_close($ch);
```

and work with it in a function env to show all calls i need.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I've done this I always create a driver class that encapsulates the HTTP functionality and a Repository class that encapsulates the service at a higher level. The driver has no idea what services it is communicating with. It just performs REST requests and returns the result. example pseudo code might be:

```
ERPRepository erpRepository = new ERPRepository();
ERPUser erpUser = erpRepository.findByUsername("testuser");
```

where `erpRepository.findByUsername` does something along the lines of:

```
public ERPUser findByUsername(username) {
  Driver driver = new Driver();
  String result = driver.get("https://erp.com/api/user/testuser"); // JSON returned
  // ERPUser knows how to parse JSON...
  ERPUser erpUser = new ERPUser(result);
  // ...or ERPRepository does it instead
  ERPUser erpUser = new ERPUser();
  ...parse the JSON...
  erpUser.setName = json.name etc
  return erpUser;
}

class Driver {
  public String get(String url) {
    ...curl commands...
  }
}
```